# What is a keyword to dynamic library export / import in linux?

Tags: linux, dynamic, import, export

I'm developing a chat server.

this is my source.

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#ifdef PENGCHAT3SERVERLIB_EXPORTS
#define PENGCHAT3SERVER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PENGCHAT3SERVER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#elif defined(__unix) // is this right?
#define PENGCHAT3SERVER_API //....?????
#endif
```

I have two questions.

first, defined(__unix) is ok?
second, what is keyword dynamic library export / import in linux?

I'm very wondering.

Please help me

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building on Linux, there is no need for a specifier or special measures; all function symbols are exported by default.

```
#define PENGCHAT3SERVER_API
```

You want to look for the `__unix__` (preferred) or `unix` defines, but you should consider making it the default instead.

Comment: WOW really? i heard that keyword. __attribute__ ((__visibility__("default"))) is this wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it says "default"? You'd only use that if you took measures to hide symbols by default.